# Error when running rails test command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While working through the Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl, I am running into an error while executing `rails test` and could use some help getting past this:

```
$ rails test
Running via Spring preloader in process 2648
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.0.4/lib/active_support/testing/declarative.rb:14:in `test': test_layout_links is already defined in SiteLayoutTest (RuntimeError)
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:5:in `<class:SiteLayoutTest>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.4/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:11:in `block in require_files'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.4/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:10:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.4/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:10:in `require_files'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.4/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:86:in `plugin_rails_init'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:81:in `block in init_plugins'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:79:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:79:in `init_plugins'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:130:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-5.0.4/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:72:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest.rb:63:in `block in autorun'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: doing ruby on rails tutorial by M Hartl

Comment: please, provide us some code or describe what did you want to do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to include some information on what you're having trouble with, so more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. I also indented your error block by 4 spaces so that it renders nicer - please see the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting. I've also added the additional information from your comment into the question to make it more apparent. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that you already have defined method `test_layout_links` in the file `test/integration/site_layout_test.rb`.

Is it possible that it occurs twice?

Like:

```
def test_layout_links
  ...
end

def test_layout_links
  ...
end
```

Or, if you use the DSL, it might look like this:

```
test "layout_links" do
  ...
end

test "layout_links" do
  ...
end
```

Either way, just delete or rename one.